# Executing a command passed from another terminal

Tags: terminal, pseudoterminal

I try to understand why, when I pass some text to a pseudoterminal by directly doing, for instance : `printf "ls" > /dev/pts/3`, pressing Enter just after doesn't result in executing the command? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Thanks to this link I made an attempt to get it work. But the solution involving ioctl and TIOCSTI seems to work only when I give the /dev/pts/0 file descriptor where 0 is the running terminal. Any solution for passing input to others?